# How to await an awaitable object while observing a CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I have an awaitable object which is NOT a `Task` (for example, an `IObservable<T>` with RX installed). I want to create a `Task`, which will end up as cancelled if the supplied `CancellationToken` is cancelled or return the result of the awaitable object otherwise. I came up with the following code:

```
public static Task ObserveTokenAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<Unit> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Unit>();
    token.Register(() => tcs.SetCanceled());
    return tcs.Task;
}

public static async Task<T> WrapObservableAsync<T>(IObservable<T> obs)
{
    return await obs;
}

public static async Task<T> AwaitWhileObservingTokenAsync<T>(IObservable<T> obs, CancellationToken token)
{
    var obsTask = WrapObservableAsync(obs);
    var tokenTask = ObserveTokenAsync(token);
    await Task.WhenAny(obsTask, tokenTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return obsTask.Result;
}
```

With this approach I will need to overload/rewrite the last two methods for each of the awaitable types I will be using. Is there any better way to do this? My guess is that the `INotifyCompletion` interface may somehow be useful.

Also, can the `ObserveTokenAsync` method cause some kind of resource/memory leaks if the supplied tokens won't get cancelled? If yes, will setting the `TaskCompletionSource` as finished at the end of the `AwaitWhileObservingTokenAsync` method will be a good way to fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to change from Rx? It's generally far more powerful.

Comment: @Enigmativity The problem I am working on is described by very complex states. I find the logic difficult to express in the functional manner. Thus, I use the RX mostly for some inter-thread communication, while the majority of the software is written in the imperative manner.

Comment: So this is a bit of an XY problem. Perhaps it might be worth your while to describe what you're actually trying to do. Rx is very good at reducing the complexity of code in some situations. Maybe it might have a very good solution here.

Comment: It's been a few years. I'm curious if you found an elegant solution? I suspect not since `OnCompleted` (in the thing returned by `GetAwaiter`) doesn't provide any feedback to the caller (it immediately returns void) nor does it provide feedback to the `Action` that's passed in (it doesn't take a `CancellationToken` or anything else as a parameter) so as [Daniel said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209638/how-to-await-an-awaitable-object-while-observing-a-cancellationtoken#comment54272219_33210919) there's no consistent notion of canceling. But I'm still curious to hear what you learned?

Comment: @MattThomas Back then I wasn't looking for a way to cancel the awaited resource (a task, an observable etc.), but for a way to interrupt the awaiting. If I had to do it again, I would probably write a generic method that takes a delegate extracting the awaiter.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `TaskObservableExtensions.ToTask` extension method from Rx. It takes a `CancellationToken` and will take the last element from the observable when available to finish the returned task. When the `CancellationToken` is canceled the returned task will throw an `OperationCanceledException` when awaited. If the observable does not contain any elements, the returned task will throw an exception when awaited (probably an `InvalidOperationException` though I would have to look that up).

Comment: That works great for RX. But in my question, the `IObservable<T>` is just an example. I am looking for a solution working with all awaitables.

Comment: Technically, C#'s determination of what can be awaited and what not is pattern based. Something can be awaited if it exposes a `GetAwaiter` method with the correct signature, and it goes on from there (check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx) for more insight). So, any solution you are aiming for would probably work with a lot of `dynamic`s and stuff.

Comment: Thinking more about it, you probably won't get far with dynamics either, since everything that can be awaited would have it's own notion of cancelling. For observables, it's unsubscribing. For something else, cancelling could be achieved some other way, if at all. It would be interesting to see how your awaitable object looks like and where it comes from.

Comment: I'm interested in any solution that can await any awaitable object (i.e. implementing a proper `GetAwaiter` method), even it requires a massive use of dynamics, reflection etc.